# Unable to boot the iOS Simulator; launchd failed to respond

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have the problem that when I launch the simulator, a black screen appears with the message:
"Unable to boot the iOS Simulator".
I'm using Xcode 6.4 with iOS 8.4 Simulator.

I have tried several solutions that are proposed on other threads, but nothing works.
(launchd.conf not found on my system) 
Is there any solution without reinstalling Xcode/OS X?

Log-File:

> Jul  8 15:10:07 WMUCM482679 CoreSimulatorService[793] : Could
>   not register service com.apple.PowerManagement.control:
>   launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0xfffffecc Jul  8 15:10:17 WMUCM482679
>   CoreSimulatorService[793] : Could not register service
>   com.apple.SystemConfiguration.configd_host:
>   launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0xfffffecc Jul  8 15:10:27 WMUCM482679
>   CoreSimulatorService[793] : Could not register service
>   com.apple.audio.coreaudiod: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0xfffffecc
>   Jul  8 15:10:37 WMUCM482679 CoreSimulatorService[793] : Could
>   not register service com.apple.SystemConfiguration.PPPController:
>   launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0xfffffecc Jul  8 15:10:37 WMUCM482679
>   CoreSimulatorService[793] : Could not register service
>   com.apple.audio.audiohald: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e Jul  8
>   15:10:37 WMUCM482679 CoreSimulatorService[793] : Could not
>   register service
>   com.apple.coreservices.lsuseractivity.simulatorsupport:
>   launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e Jul  8 15:10:37 WMUCM482679
>   CoreSimulatorService[793] : Could not register service
>   com.apple.FSEvents: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e Jul  8
>   15:10:37 WMUCM482679 CoreSimulatorService[793] : Could not
>   register service com.apple.SystemConfiguration.configd:
>   launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e Jul  8 15:10:37 WMUCM482679
>   CoreSimulatorService[793] : Could not register service
>   IndigoHIDRegistrationPort: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e Jul  8
>   15:10:37 WMUCM482679 CoreSimulatorService[793] : Could not
>   register service PurpleFBTVOutServer: launch_sim_register_endpoint:
>   0x44e Jul  8 15:10:37 WMUCM482679 CoreSimulatorService[793] :
>   Could not register service PurpleFBServer:
>   launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e Jul  8 15:10:37 WMUCM482679
>   CoreSimulatorService[793] : Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain
>   Code=60 "Unable to boot the iOS Simulator." UserInfo=0x7f8c70d18fd0
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to boot the iOS Simulator.,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=launchd failed to respond.} Jul  8 15:10:37
>   WMUCM482679 CoreSimulatorService[793] : Error
>   Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=60 "Unable to boot the iOS Simulator."
>   UserInfo=0x7f8c70d18fd0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to boot the iOS
>   Simulator., NSLocalizedFailureReason=launchd failed to respond.} Jul 
>   8 15:10:37 WMUCM482679 com.apple.iphonesimulator[902] : Error
>   Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=60 "Unable to boot the iOS Simulator."
>   UserInfo=0x7fcf53a01aa0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to boot the iOS
>   Simulator., NSLocalizedFailureReason=launchd failed to respond.} Jul 
>   8 15:10:37 WMUCM482679 CoreSimulatorService[793] : Error
>   Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=146 "Unable to lookup in
>   current state: Shutdown" UserInfo=0x7f8c70d18fd0
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown}
>   Jul  8 15:10:37 WMUCM482679 CoreSimulatorService[793] : Error
>   looking up host support port

Comment: Have you found the solution ??

Comment: I have completely same as your issues in macOS 10.13.6 and Xcode 10.0, 10.1. Was it solved?

Answer (score 4):

For those who are still facing this issue, I found another answer which saved my day.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32240747/8550847

Comment: Please don't add another answer link in your answer. Better add that link in the comment section.

Answer (score 1):

First check your OS X version, because Xcode `6.4` works only in later versions of `10.10`.

Second if you have copied Xcode from a `DMG file` then it should be copied in the **Applications folder**.

Comment: thanks for your fast reply! I'm using OS X 10.10.4. Xcode is in Applications folder. Maybe I should also mention that it has already been working... since this week it's not working any more.

Comment: I have completely same as your issues in macOS 10.13.6 and Xcode 10.0, 10.1.
Was it solved?

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to delete and recreate my simulators to fix the problem. I followed [this](https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-fix-unable-to-boot-the-ios-simulator/) and did `fastlane snapshot reset_simulators` to do it using Fastlane.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me. I think the reason was, that I am still using macOS Monterey 12.4 because my machine can't run the new macOS anymore.