# Unable to boot the iOS Simulator after deleting /private/tmp

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, simulator

This week I cannot boot my Simulator, I tried several solutions from some articles, but it doesn't work. My MacOS version is OS X 10.10.5 (14F27), and my Simulator is iOS 8.4.

I grabbed the log from *~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log*

> Aug 27 11:29:14 LL-MBP.local CoreSimulatorService[8316] : Could
>   not register service com.apple.SystemConfiguration.PPPController:
>   launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0xfffffecc Aug 27 11:29:14 LL-MBP.local
>   CoreSimulatorService[8316] : Could not register service
>   com.apple.audio.audiohald: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e Aug 27
>   11:29:14 LL-MBP.local CoreSimulatorService[8316] : Could not
>   register service
>   com.apple.coreservices.lsuseractivity.simulatorsupport:
>   launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e Aug 27 11:29:14 LL-MBP.local
>   CoreSimulatorService[8316] : Could not register service
>   com.apple.FSEvents: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e Aug 27
>   11:29:14 LL-MBP.local CoreSimulatorService[8316] : Could not
>   register service com.apple.SystemConfiguration.configd:
>   launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e Aug 27 11:29:14 LL-MBP.local
>   CoreSimulatorService[8316] : Could not register service
>   IndigoHIDRegistrationPort: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e Aug 27
>   11:29:14 LL-MBP.local CoreSimulatorService[8316] : Could not
>   register service PurpleFBTVOutServer: launch_sim_register_endpoint:
>   0x44e Aug 27 11:29:14 LL-MBP.local CoreSimulatorService[8316] :
>   Could not register service PurpleFBServer:
>   launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e Aug 27 11:29:14 LL-MBP.local
>   CoreSimulatorService[8316] : Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain
>   Code=60 "Unable to boot the iOS Simulator." UserInfo=0x7fbb204683f0
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to boot the iOS Simulator.,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=launchd failed to respond.} Aug 27 11:29:14
>   LL-MBP.local CoreSimulatorService[8316] : Error
>   Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=60 "Unable to boot the iOS Simulator."
>   UserInfo=0x7fbb204683f0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to boot the iOS
>   Simulator., NSLocalizedFailureReason=launchd failed to respond.} Aug
>   27 11:29:14 LL-MBP.local CoreSimulatorService[8316] : Error
>   Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=146 "Unable to lookup in
>   current state: Shutdown" UserInfo=0x7fbb20808710
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown}
>   Aug 27 11:29:14 LL-MBP.local CoreSimulatorService[8316] : Error
>   looking up host support port Aug 27 11:29:14 LL-MBP.local
>   CoreSimulatorService[8316] : Error
>   Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=146 "Invalid device
>   state" UserInfo=0x7fbb2083b420 {NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid device
>   state} Aug 27 11:29:14 LL-MBP.local CoreSimulatorService[8316]
>   : Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=146
>   "Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown" UserInfo=0x7fbb2080c350
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown}
>   Aug 27 11:29:14 LL-MBP.local CoreSimulatorService[8316] : Error
>   Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=146 "Unable to lookup in
>   current state: Shutdown" UserInfo=0x7fbb2080c350
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown}
>   Aug 27 11:29:14 LL-MBP.local com.apple.iphonesimulator[8330] :
>   Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=60 "Unable to boot the iOS
>   Simulator." UserInfo=0x7fda2a9020f0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to
>   boot the iOS Simulator., NSLocalizedFailureReason=launchd failed to
>   respond.} Aug 27 11:29:14 LL-MBP.local CoreSimulatorService[8316]
>   : Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=146
>   "Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown" UserInfo=0x7fbb20b0f850
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown}
>   Aug 27 11:29:14 LL-MBP.local CoreSimulatorService[8316] : Error
>   looking up host support port Aug 27 11:29:14 LL-MBP.local
>   CoreSimulatorService[8316] : Error
>   Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=146 "Invalid device
>   state" UserInfo=0x7fbb20b00e20 {NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid device
>   state}

Does someone have any idea about this?

I will appreciate it!

Finally I fixed this issue with @Jeremy Huddleston Sequoia 's help. At the beginning, I tried lots of solutions online, including remove /private/tmp folder. so that caused no matter how many times I clean reinstall simulator, it doesn't work. so be careful about this

Comment: Did you restart the computer?

Comment: Updated the title now that we know the cause.  Hopefully that will help grab the attention of others searching for the same problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those errors indicate that launchd_sim is not loaded or not running, and the watchdog fired to notify you of the failure.

If you disable AMFI in OS X 10.10.5, the Simulator runtime will be unusable, and it can manifest like this.

However, in your case, launchd_sim is crashing on launch.  The crash log indicates that it is encountering an error when trying to create its state directory in /private/tmp.

This can happen you deleted /private/tmp (or incorrectly recreated it).  To create /private/tmp do:

```
sudo mkdir /private/tmp
sudo chmod 1777 /private/tmp
```

Comment: Here is my system.log while I was trying to boot xcode and simulator:

Comment: Class IDEBlockScrollView is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/IDEKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEProductsUI.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDEProductsUI. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Aug 27 14:57:51 LL-MBP.local com.apple.usbmuxd[77]: LOCKDOWN_V2_BONJOUR_SERVICE_NAME is _apple-mobdev2._tcp,90a107ed

Comment: I checked I have no boot-args configuration                    nvram: Error getting variable - 'boot-argus': (iokit/common) data was not found

Comment: There's certainly a lot more in system.log.  That particular line you quoted isn't relevant here.  Please also look for any launchd_sim crash logs.

Comment: the log is too long to be pasted here, can you give me a email address, so that I can send it to you?

Comment: You can use pastebin and then provide the url here.

Comment: Updated answer.  I suspect you have incorrect permissions on /private/tmp.  Please also provide the output of `ls -al /private/tmp`

Comment: yinhaoliang@LL-MBP:~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator$ ls -al /private/tmp
ls: /private/tmp: No such file or directory

Comment: seems I don't have the directory, I remember I tried some suggestion from some post to remove this folder before

Comment: Can you point me to that post, so I can comment about that being a horrible suggestion?  Please recreate it (see updated answer).

Comment: yinhaoliang@LL-MBP:/private/tmp$ ls -al
total 0
drwxrwxrwt  2 root  wheel   68 Aug 28 11:19 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 6 root  wheel  204 Aug 28 11:19 ..

Comment: ahh.. since I queried lot's of posts during this week, I may not be able to find that article again, I will try and keep update to you once I find it.

Comment: Thanks very much and appreciate this. It's working fine now, pretty cool! I'm new on iOS development, it's really a tough problem but good experience

Comment: Glad to help.  Can you please still point me to the post with advice that caused you to break your system?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot find that post, but next time if I see it again, I will point you to it.

Comment: this solved my issue, thank you! Tried everything else after removing some folders due to Xcode eating all of my storage. Accidentally deleted this folder and simulators were not working anymore. Even tried to uninstall and reinstall Xcode which didn't work. Thankfully found your solution which worked perfectly! Thnx